# How to insert specific IP address in to postman's header, or other similar test tool?

Tags: node.js, express, networking, ip

I am trying to make some tests on my backend protection logic, and I want to see if someone can change his ip manually and send a get request to my website that has to be assessable
only from certain ips neither from outside those range of ips,

```js
let ipRange = ['75.21.323.32', '52.57.66.799','98.89.88.77']

const getIP = require('ipware')().get_ip;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const ip= getIP(req);
   if(ipRange.includes(ip)){
   // Allow acess
   } else {
   res.send({erorr : 'no ip acess'})
   }
});
```

any idea how to make those tests using postman or similar tool that could allow you to manipulate you get request ip address if this could be even possible ?

Comment: First off, you middleware is not correctly implemented.  You need to move the call to `next()` to inside the if block: `if(...) { next()} else { ... }` so you ONLY call `next()` when the IP address is approved.  Right now, you are always calling `next()` which (even though you send a response) still causes other request handlers to execute which won't get the remote client any data because the response stream has already been closed, but could allow POST or PUT requests through which could change things on your server.

Comment: It's quite difficult to spoof a source IP address in a TCP connection because TCP requires roundtrip communication to establish the socket.  If you're spoofing the source address, then you can't participate in the roundtrip communication because traffic is sent to the spoofed address, not yours.  It's not something you can do from postman.

Comment: sorry for that, any idea how to test this externally, i want to try to access this from out side network that has different ip and change that different ip in to the ip in the array of range so i can test if someone can access if for some reason he got the ip and figured out my logic, any specific tools in mind ?

Comment: Go to your local coffee shop that has WiFi and try it from there.  Or, set up a VPN so your traffic is coming from the VPN server rather than from your own client host.  You can probably even do a free trial of a VPN client such as NordVPN or ExpressVPN.

Comment: it wont work , i tried my phone hotspot, but I want to intentionally try to throw a wrench at this logic by using some tool.. and see if it will pass if this tool even exists, and from there try to improve on this logic.

Comment: Then, it's unclear what you're really trying to prove here.

Comment: basically I want to see if someone can get the ip in range, after conneting to my network, and later try to act like he is sending a get request from that ip even if he is not actually connected to my network.

Comment: Someone can send the first packet of a TCP connect request from a spoofed IP address, but they cannot complete the TCP connection because doing so requires roundtrip data and a hacker sending spoofed IP address packets does not receive the return packets because they aren't at the IP address that they spoofed (unless they  also control one of your routers).  You may want to read this: [Is it possible to pass TCP handshake with spoofed IP address](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/is-it-possible-to-pass-tcp-handshake-with-spoofed-ip-address).

Comment: I should mention that the library you're using to get the IP address looks for a variety of headers on the http request which is assuming that the request has been routed through some sort of local proxy and thus the original IP address is available via a header on the request.   For this to be safe and not spoofable, the proxy has to reject any such headers on incoming requests. Usually, a proxy will reject or remove whatever headers it is configured to use to avoid spoofing via headers, but that really depends upon your proxy configuration. So, your proxy has to be configured properly too.

Comment: And, you have to make sure the `ipware.get_ip()` function is configured properly to only look for the IP address headers that your proxy is using so any other headers that could be spoofed won't be used by accident.  By default ipware looks for 10 different possible headers in a specific order.  You can configure which headers it looks for and in which order it checks for them.  This should be configured to only use the header that your proxy is actually using.

Comment: do you know of any tools or packages that can spoof ips so I can make those tests ? cannot find any.. been looking for hours.

Comment: I just told you I don't know how to spoof a source IP address of a TCP connection and still have a functioning connection (it basically isn't possible without taking over your local router).  Thus, I don't know of any tools to do so.  If your ipware is not configured properly, it would be easy to set one of the custom headers with a permitted IP address, but you should first configure ipware correct so it doesn't use any header other than what your local proxy is using.

Comment: makes a lot of sense this way... it will filter all unwanted headers making it clean and secure, very good point.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send a GET request from a spoofed IP address because just  establishing the TCP connection requires round-trip communication and if the attacker has spoofed the source IP address then the return data from setting up the TCP connection will not go back to the attacker, it will go to the spoofed IP address which will fail to complete the TCP connection.  Note, UDP has more vulnerabilities in this regard.  Thus, the only way the attacker could make that work is if they had control of your local router and thus could intercept the outgoing traffic that was going back to the spoofed IP address.

Even if they could successfully establish a TCP connection, the result of the GET request would again go back to the spoofed IP address, not the attacker's address.

In order to be compatible with local proxy servers (which are used in most hosting environments), your ipware library is also looking a variety of headers on the request that the proxy could use to tell your endpoint what the original IP address was.  For this to be secure, you have to do several things:

1. Make sure that your instance of ipware is configured to ONLY use the one and only one header that your proxy is using to communicate the original IP address to you.
2. Make sure that your proxy is configured to only pass the IP address that it saw, not append to a list of IP addresses that may have already been present on the incoming request.
3. If you can't do #2, then you must make sure that you have configured ipware to use the most recent IP address only (the IP address that your proxy was connected to from) as this header can consist of a list of IP addresses (some of which could be spoofed - the ones that came from the request before it arrived at your proxy).  Depending upon how your proxy works with appending of IP addresses, you may have to tell ipware whether to use the first or last IP address in the list (known as left-most or right-most).  Proxies are not all the same in this implementation so you have to test how yours works.  See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/846489/can-x-forwarded-for-contain-multiple-ips) for examples of multiple IP addresses in the proxy header.
4. Make sure your proxy is not permitting spoofing of whichever header it is using to communicate the IP address.